# appending a new function at the end of list of functions assigned to a javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say, I've a input button like this:

```
<code>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="fxn1();fxn2();fxn3();"/>
</code>
```

Now, i wan't to add a new function fxn() (prepend or append) to the list of functions already assigned to onclick event. How would I do that? Also, the number of functions assigned to onclick is not known and hence can be anything greater than 0 or even 0 sometimes.

Comment: Do you care about knowing how many functions are already assigned? Or would you be happy with just adding a new function, regardless of the existence of the others?

Comment: I'd definitely prefer to know about the functions that are already attached(not for now, but someday I might come across a situation like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`jQuery.Callbacks`](http://api.jquery.com/category/callbacks-object/) do the needful. introduces in **jQuery v1.7**

*The following are two sample methods named **fn1** and **fn2**:*

```
function fn1( value ){
    console.log( value );
}

function fn2( value ){
    fn1("fn2 says:" + value);
    return false;
}    

// Supported Flags : 
// once: Ensures the callback list can only be fired once (like a Deferred).

var callbacks = $.Callbacks( "once" );
callbacks.add( fn1 );
callbacks.fire( "foo" );
callbacks.add( fn2 );
callbacks.fire( "bar" );
callbacks.remove( fn2 );
callbacks.fire( "foobar" );
```

**[`Reference`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care whether it's prepended or appended or even inserted in the middle, and since you're already using jQuery (based on the tag you assigned the question), then use `.click()` to add the new function as a listener for the click event.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating:  http://jsfiddle.net/trott/b67zN/2/

Or if you just want to see the code here, demo HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="clickme" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="alert('foo');"/>
```

And demo JS looks like this:

```
function secondListener() {
    alert('bar');
}

$('#clickme').click(secondListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter your functions as a part of already assigned function. What I mean is instead of appending new function on some condition call those functions from your one and only onclick function based on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Its just as simple as `$('input').click(fxn);`

And you may need to remove any handler from that element in future.
You could use [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) for that. But it will remove all the click handlers that have been attached to the element.

To avoid it and to remove just one event handler, you can do [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) with [namespace](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events).

```
$('input').bind('click.fxn', fxn);
```

`'click.fxn'`, can be explained as `event name(click)` followed by a `.` and `some string(fxn)` to distinguish the specific event handler.

So, if you want to remove `fxn` function you could do `$('input').unbind('click.fxn')`.
It will only remove the fxn handler.

I hope this helps.